# Finding integer solutions of polynomials division

Tags: polynomials, diophantine-equations, integers, rational-numbers

How can I find the integer solutions of the following problem

$\frac{2+16x-x^2}{2(3+x)}$

e.g. if $x=2$ then we have $\frac{30}{10}=3$

### Context

I have a data with infinity columns and rows.
I need to start at a cell and pick a path to go to another cell

e.g. If I pick `57` as start point and want to go to `55` as my goal, I need to move two cell right ($x=+2$) and three cell up (= $-3$ cell down) ($y=-3$)

| $i$ | $x_1=1$ | $x_2=2$ | $x_3=3$ | $x_4=4$ | $x_5=5$ | $x_6=6$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 15 | 28 | 39 | 48 | 55 | 60 |
| 9 | 17 | 32 | 45 | 56 | 65 | 72 |
| 10 | 19 | 36 | 51 | 64 | 75 | 84 |
| 11 | 21 | 40 | 57 | 72 | 85 | 96 |
| 12 | 23 | 44 | 63 | 80 | 95 | 108 |
| 13 | 25 | 48 | 69 | 88 | 105 | 120 |
| 14 | 27 | 52 | 75 | 96 | 115 | 132 |
| 15 | 29 | 56 | 81 | 104 | 125 | 144 |
| 16 | 31 | 60 | 87 | 112 | 135 | 156 |
| 17 | 33 | 64 | 93 | 120 | 145 | 168 |
| 18 | 35 | 68 | 99 | 128 | 155 | 180 |

### Formula

For `x` move to right we have :

$value_{(n+x,i)}=value_{(n,i)}+(({o_{(n-1)}}_i)^2-({o_{(n-1-x)}}_i)^2)$

For `y` move to down we have :

$value_{(n,i+y)}=value_{(n,i)}+2*y_n*y$ ($y_n$ changes when we move horizontally and depended on $x$, see general form)

and

${o_(n)}_i = 2*i-2(x_n-1)-1$

and

$x_n=n$

In **general form**, For `x` move to right and `y` move to down we have

$value_{(n+x,i+y)}=value_{(n,i)}+(({o_{(n-1)}}_i)^2-({o_{(n-1-x)}}_i)^2)+value_{(n,i)}+2*(x_n+x)*y$

### Example

In cell `57` we have `x_3=3` and `i=11`, I am looking for a $x$ and $y$ to move to cell `55`. The correct answer is $x=2$ and $y=-3$

I think the best solution for my problem is changing it to another problem (if you have better solution let me know)

For some boring reasons, I know that $57+(({o_{(2)}}_{11})^2-({o_{(2-x)}}_{11})^2)-55$ is dividable by $2*(x_3+x)$

which convert problem to finding integer solution for $\frac{2+16x-x^2}{2(3+x)}$

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: OK, wait a moment, I am editing it

Comment: $\frac{2+16x-x^2}{2(3+x)}$ is just an expression, it doesn't have "integer solutions"... perhaps you are asking for which integers $x$ (again guessing, you are not saying what $x$ is) is the given expression an integer, or equivalently what are integer solutions of $\frac{2+16x-x^2}{2(3+x)}=y$ ?

Comment: You are right, let me say "Which integer $x$ make the result expression an integer, not fraction"

Comment: There are too many corrections and backtracks here. If everyone is misunderstanding the question, then the problem probably is the way the question is written. It is on the person writing the question to be clear, please!

Comment: Sorry for causing confusion, It was so complex to me to define the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $2(x+3)$ divides $-x^2+16x+2$, then $x+3$ divides $-x^2+16x+2$. By polynomial long division $$-x^2+16x+2=(x+3)(-x+19)-55.$$
Hence $x+3$ divides $55$, i.e. $x+3\in \{\pm 1, \pm 5, \pm 11, \pm 55\}$. Thus $$x \in \{-58, -14, -8, -4, -2, 2, 8, 52\}.$$
We can check that indeed all of these $x$ values give an integer for the original expression.

Comment: Thank you for your solution, it's very simple, But I don't know how can I convert it to a code! Anyway it helps a lot.

Answer (score 1):

For there to be integer solutions there must be integer solutions to the radical below.
\begin{align*}
\frac{2+16x-x^2}{2(3+x)}&=n\\
\implies x &= \pm\sqrt{n^2 - 22 n + 66} - n + 8
\end{align*}

The solutions are complex for $4\le n\le18$ but, for $\, -2500\le n \le 2500, \,$

\begin{align*}
n&\in\big\{-17,-17,3,3,19,19,39,39\big\}\\
\implies x&\in\big\{-2,52,2,8,-14,-8,-58,-4 \big\}
\end{align*} respectively.

Comment: Can you please explain your solution in more details? Where does the radical come from?

Comment: @WebMaster All I did was solve the original equation for $\,x\,$ in terms of $\,n\,$ and then tried a range of $\,n$-values in a spreadsheet to see which yielded integers. For those, I evaluated the right side of the equation for both the positive and negative values from the radical.

Answer (score -1):

Note that for there to be an integer solution, $2(3 + x)$ must divide $2 + 16x - x^2$. Or, to put this in terms of congruences, there is an integer solution precisely when $2 + 16x - x^2 \equiv 0 (mod\ 6 + 2x)$. Mind, you can't divide by zero - so there is no solution when $x = -3$.

If you add 4 to both sides then you'll have $6 + 16x - x^2 \equiv (6 + 2x) + 14x - x^2 
\equiv 14x - x^2 \equiv 4 (mod\ 6 + 2x)$.

Note that $14 / 2 = 7$. So if we add $6 * 7 = 42$ to both sides then we can eliminate the $14x$ from the congruence altogether.

$42 + 14x - x^2 \equiv 7(6 + 2x) - x^2 \equiv -x^2 \equiv 46 (mod\ 6 + 2x)$.

Thus there is an integer solution wherever $x^2 \equiv -46 (mod\ 6 + 2x)$. Or equivalently, there is a solution when $x^2 = (6 + 2x)k - 46$ for some integer $k$.

Rearranging terms we get $x^2 -2kx -6k + 46 = 0$. See if you can find solutions in terms of $k$ by using the Quadratic Formula with a = 1, b = -2k, c = -6k + 46. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have eddied my question and add context and more information. Your solution is perfect for my first question, but for my practical problem it cause a lot of calculation and increase time complexity

Comment: Can you please refer me to a page that shows me how can I find integer solutions of a Quadratic Formula

Comment: @WebMaster I’m not sure of a formula or algorithm to get only integer solutions out of a Quadratic Equation generally. But if you have reduced the results of the Quadratic Equation in terms of k then you can derive some hints based upon the numerator and denominator like I did above for the original equation. In general, Diophantine Equations are difficult

Comment: 1/ It would be helpful to make it clear at the start that you don't have a complete solution.$\quad$  2/ To complete your approach, for a monic quadratic to have integer roots, you need the discriminant to be a perfect square of the same parity as the linear coefficient, and we can solve the diophantine quadratic accordingly. EG $k = -31$ gives us $ (-2k)^2 - 4(1)(-6k+46) = 54^2$, and the integer solution is $ (-62 \pm 54 )/2 = -4, -58$.

Comment: @CalvinLin you enjoying going around to all my posts?